# using regex with syslog-ng input file

Tags: logging, unix-timestamp, syslog-ng

i use syslog-ng for logging Application Logs to remote Destinations.

I have application logs in the following pattern:  `javaservice.2017-05-11.log` and i want to use a regex at the Source definition like:

```
file("/var/log/javaservice/javaservice.*.log"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be possible in the upcoming 3.10 version of the syslog-ng Open Source Edition (the commercial version already has this feature). You can find [developer RPM builds of syslog-ng here](https://www.balabit.com/blog/rpm-packages-from-syslog-ng-git-head/), and test this feature. See the [docs for using wildcards in syslog-ng file sources](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.10-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-sources-wildcard-file.html).